Forest (linguistics) adding boxes and outer title
I have the following tree and I need to add another box and some text as illustrated in the second pic:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[linguistics]{forest}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
    \begin{forest}
        [1,tikz={\node [draw,red,fit=(!1)(!2)] {}; \node [draw,red,fit=()()] {};}[2[2a][2b][2c][2d]][3[3a][3b][3c]]]
    \end{forest}
\end{document}


This is what I would like:


You can add a label to each fit node. Also, you can name tree nodes to use later in your fit commands.

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[linguistics]{forest}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
    \begin{forest}
        [1,name=n1[2,name=n2[2a,name=n2a][2b][2c][2d]][3,name=n3[3a][3b][3c,name=n3c]]]
        \node[draw,red,fit=(n1), label=east:Level 1]{};
        \node[draw,red,fit=(n2)(n3), label=east:Level 2]{};
        \node[draw,red,fit=(n2a)(n3c), label=east:Level 3]{};
    \end{forest}
\end{document}


The following defines a forest style boxed levels which takes an optional argument. By default, a box is drawn around the nodes of each level using the current colour etc. The optional argument may be used to override the default style. For example, here we use boxed levels={draw=red}. A label is also created for each level.
[A more sophisticated version would allow customisation of the label, but that gets a bit more complex in terms of providing a user interface.]
The upshot is that, for example,
  \begin{forest}
    boxed levels={draw=red},
    [1
      [2[2a][2b][2c][2d]][3[3a][3b][3c]]
    ]
  \end{forest}

produces

The basic idea is to find the number of levels after the tree is constructed but before it is drawn. The names of each node on each level are then collected in a toks variable which is fed into a fit= using tikz+. This means we know both the nodes we want to fit and the number of the level for each iteration and can construct the box programmatically.
Complete code:
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[linguistics]{forest}
% ateb: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/720008/ addaswyd o gwestiwn Frank: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/719963/
\forestset{%
  boxed levels/.style={%
    before drawing tree={%
      tempcounta/.max={level}{tree},
      tempcountb'=-1,
      for nodewalk={%
        root,
        until={>RR={tempcountb}{tempcounta}}{%
          tempcountb'+=1,
          temptoksa={},
          for level/.process={ Rw{tempcountb}{##1{%
                temptoksa+/.process={ Ow{name}{(####1)}},
              }%
            }%
          },
          tikz+/.process={ RRw+nw2{temptoksa}{tempcountb}{##1+1}{
              \node [draw,fit=##1,label=right:{Level ##2},#1] {};  
            }%
          },     
        }%
      }{},
    },
  },
}
\begin{document}
  \begin{forest}
    boxed levels={draw=red},
    [1
      [2[2a][2b][2c][2d]][3[3a][3b][3c]]
    ]
  \end{forest}
\end{document}

